# WordPress widget with several templates

Tags: php, wordpress

There are two areas in my theme for widgets. But what should I do if I want to define two different templates to the same widget? a template to the widget when it's in X area and other template to the **same** widget when it's in Y area.

The format of the widget is normal:

```
class some_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function some_widget() { .. }

    function widget() { .. }

    function update() { .. }

    function form() { .. }

}
```

`widget()` includes the template of the widget.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first parameter of widget function, you will find the sidebar id and name, for example :

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  if ($args['id']=='sidebar-1') {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

To get the name of the sidebar instead of id, just use `$args['name']`

But before trying this, did you try with different css rules ?

Comment: Different CSS rules won't help me because the areas are displayed in the same page. In addition I there is another structure to each area. Well.. I think your way is the only one. Thank you.